# Double integral with four regions

Tags: integration

Find the following integratal?
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \lvert \pi - \lvert x-y \rvert \rvert e^{ax} e^{ay} dx dy, \qquad a\in\mathbb R$$

Comment: As the title says, split your integral into four regions in such a way that you don't need the absolute values anymore.

Comment: I tried to do that but my attempt was incorrect...I am looking forward to your feedback

Comment: Hint: the necessary boundaries between the regions are all parallel to the line y=x.

Comment: I tried to do this but the partitioning was not correct.

Comment: How can we give feedback without you showing your attempt to us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a map of the regions...

[image]

$\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\int_{x+\pi}^{2\pi} ((y-x)-\pi)e^{a(x+y)}\ dy \ dx\\ 
+\displaystyle \int_0^\pi\int_x^{x+\pi} (\pi - (y-x))e^{a(x+y)}\ dy \ dx\\
+\displaystyle \int_0^\pi\int_0^{x} (\pi - (x-y))e^{a(x+y)}\ dy \ dx\\
+\displaystyle\int_\pi^{2\pi}\int_{x}^{2\pi} (\pi - (y-x))e^{a(x+y)}\ dy \ dx + \cdots$

Comment: Can you add the remaining two regions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general way to approach problems like this.

First, identify the various ways the values can combine together
such that the absolute value signs can be removed.
Starting with $|\pi−|x−y||$ it would be very strange indeed if all your
four regions ended up as $\pm (\pi-x+y).$ Indeed when $x = 0$ and $y = \pi$
we find that $|\pi−|x−y|| = 0$ but $\pi-x+y = 2\pi,$
so that is definitely a mistake.

Second, identify the regions within the overall region of integration where each of the different non-absolute-value expressions are found.
(Alternatively, you can do this step first and the other step second.)

Now you can write a completely separate integral for each region.
You should then have four integrals each ending in $dx\,dy.$

Finally, **if** you find that all four integrals have the same minimum and maximum $y$ value, you may consider combining them in one $dy$ integral as you have done.
(Hint: for this problem the four integrals do not all have the same range of $y,$
so you have made another error.)